How to get joe to run in the terminal
I'm using Joe now, and now I have a problem, I'm using win10, I've installed the joe editor, and I want it to run joe inside the powershell terminal, but I don't know what the command is or what the configuration is?
I want it to run inside the terminal, but I want to know what the command is

What method did you use to install it?
